# How to fill up Spring Security Authentication Details?

Tags: json, spring, security, grails

I have a custom Provider for my API in Grails (Spring Security):

```
@Component class ApiAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

    @Autowired
    TokenGenerator tokenGenerator

    @Autowired
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder

    @Autowired
    ApiTokenStorageService tokenStorageService

    @Override
    Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
    ...
    authentication.getDetails()     }
```

Now I have the Json i send:
`{
    "username" : "username",
    "password" : "password123",
    "details"  : {"uuid":"0000-0000-0000-0000-0000000"}
}`

I can get the username and password in the authenticate methode but not the "uuid". How does these details from Authentication works?